# How can I sort the contents of sub folders and files with date created and make change (sort by) in the windows explorer of the system folder?

Tags: python, pandas, directory, operating-system

How can I sort the file and subfolders inside the main folder?

I have a folder (buro) in desktop with 1152 subfolders and 12 .csv files in each of them. I want all of them to be sorted with the modification date. What I had found in my searches is to create a list and sort them. But can I make changes in the way we can see on the windows explorer?

Can you please help with it?

Comment: Can you please describe what position of the date means? I have date of the file and folders since the last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give a sorted list (based on modification time) of all files/folders inside the folder **buro** :

```
import os
path_to_buro = "Desktop_path" # path where the folder buro is
buro = "buro" # name of the folder
sorted_files = [os.path.join(path_to_buro,buro,fold) for fold in os.listdir(os.path.join(path_to_buro,buro))]
sorted_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x),reverse=True)
```

To edit file/folder datetime according to this [link](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/change-file-modification-time-in-python/), tested in windows:

```
year = 2019
month = 9
day = 11
hour = 15
minute = 30
second = 0

date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)
modification_time = time.mktime(date.timetuple())

for fileLocation in sorted_files:
    os.utime(fileLocation, (modification_time , modification_time ))
```

Comment: what should I assign to 'buro' variable?

Comment: buro = 'buro' (the name of your folder) and path_to_buro = "absolute_path_where_the_folder_buro" (Desktop_path)

Comment: then buro has to be 'buro'?

Comment: yes, please check edits. Just tested now and working for me. Play with "reverse" parameter to sort descending or ascending

Comment: Thank you. But what might be the problem? It is not working for me. My path_to_buro=r"C:\Users\ABANISH\Desktop" . Is it correct?

Comment: in Windows the path format might affect, use path_to_buro="C:\\Users\\ABANISH\\Desktop" instead

Comment: It is still not providing the expected result. What might be the reason?

Comment: Is the result list has something in common with the modification date in the Windows File Explorer ? (in my case it worked)

Comment: When I print 'sorted_files', the printed result is perfect. But does not it change in the windows explorer too?

Comment: This is another question to be answered separatly. Please ask it in another tab. Otherwise no one will answer. Vote up if you find the answer to the first question useful.

Comment: Please check new edits, mark as answered / vote up if is useful. Thanks

Comment: Will you vote up mine question too because I would like it?

Comment: Done, please mark it as resolved if you have your question answered. So it can be useful for the Stack community

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import os
path = add_your_path

files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.csv", recursive=True)]
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:    def sorted_ls(path1):
        import glob
        import os
        path = path1
        files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.csv", recursive=True)]
        files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)

    sorted_ls("C:/Users/Elite/Desktop/kro_ro")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#Path of your directory

file = "/home/cso/user/"

file_list = []
date_modified = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(file):
    for f in files:
        file_list.append(f)
        date_modified.append(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))



df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(file_list, date_modified)), columns =['File', 'Date_modified'])
df = df.sort_values(by = 'Date_modified')
```

Comment: I can sort a list in python with this but does it make the change on the folder too?

Answer (score 0):

**first** you should make a function to get the date of file modified.

```
import time
import os 


# format the data str
def time_stamp2time(timestamp):
    times_truct = time.localtime(timestamp)
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',times_truct)


def get_file_create_time(file_path):
    t = os.path.getctime(file_path)
    return time_stamp2time(t)


def get_file_modify_time(file_path):
    t = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
    return time_stamp2time(t)
```

**then** you need walk you folders to get you all csv file

```
import os
def get_all_file_path(folder_path):
    file_path_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for name in files:
            file_path_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        # if you want get the sub folders path you can use it 
        #for name in dirs:
        #    print(os.path.join(root, name))
    return file_path_list
```

**finnaly** you can use `list.sort` or `sorted` to get your wanted result

```
# defined your desktop path 
your_desktop_path = "/home/username/" # maybe some others
folder_path= os.path.join(your_desktop_path ,"buro")
file_path_list = get_all_file_path(folder_path)
# you can use sorted instead
file_path_list.sort(key=get_file_modify_time)
```

Comment: With this, I can sort a list in python but does it make the change on the folder too?

Comment: nope , if you want sort you folder on windows ,  there are  colums can sort by modified data,
If i remember correctly